# Oracle Procedure VARCHAR2 Parameter Size limit

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Good Morning.

I am facing a very strange problem. I have an Oracle stored procedure which will accept a VARCHAR2 parameter.

From my ASP.NET application, I am calling this stored procedure and passing a comma separated string to this parameter.
The length of the comma separated string is 700 characters (including commas).

Now the problem is Oracle procedure is returning the error "3421: Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation".

If I delete some content of the input string and send it to procedure, then it is running successfully.

I read that VARCHAR2 in Oracle accepts a maximum of 4000 characters. I am sending only 700 characters. Still it is not taking it.

I tried to give the size to the procedure parameter. But it is giving compilation error and I read that we can't specify the size to oracle procedure prameter.

Can you please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks
Srinivas

Input String that is sent to VAR33 in SP_TESTPROC procedure:

```
    195083,195320,195815,196311,196247,196866,197002,197271,197294,197998,198107,
195322,195501,196537,196887,198194,198964,195125,196153,196454,196587,197158,
197082,197277,197482,198110,198312,196586,196403,196428,196510,196694,197075,
197543,198111,198351,195215,196399,197697,198200,198338,196267,195851,196069,
196435,197154,196411,196883,196898,196384,196892,196826,197138,198123,198590,
197384,196383,196438,197044,197831,198917,195787,198199,198120,195874,197155,
197262,197264,197447,198193,195730,196886,196891,196899,197076,198502,196232,
196538,196603,196857,196263,195380,196660,198041,198763,195616,195720,196430,
197559,197836,197844,198015,198666,195777,195951,196433,196795,195843,196398,
196448 




create or replace PROCEDURE   SP_TESTPROC 
     (VAR33  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
      RC1 IN OUT OMWB_EMULATION.GLOBALPKG.RCT1)
AS

BEGIN

        OPEN RC1 FOR
          SELECT *
          FROM   TABLE1 A
            INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.TABLE1ID
          WHERE A.ID IN (select TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(SPCWKF_CASEASSIGNMASTERQUERY.VAR33,'[^,]+', 1, level)) from dual
                        connect by regexp_substr(SPCWKF_CASEASSIGNMASTERQUERY.VAR33, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);

END SP_TESTPROC;
```

Comment: A bit of code might help to analyze your problem... it might also help to know database version, driver version etc.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Message clearly states *wrong type*, not anything about *size*. Is that the full literal error message? No ORA-... prefix?

Comment: There is no ORA prefix to it. The Parameter type is VARCHAR2. I am passing string to it. The problem is coming only when the input string is more than 104 characters.

Comment: AmmoQ & T_77: Sorry I can't post the code here because of my company strict rules.

Comment: BTW, i tried modifying the prameter type in procedure to NVARCHAR2. Still I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Can you try to knock up a small example bit of code that demonstrates the issue? You can obsure the table/variable/parameter names and data being passed across if needs be.

Comment: what's the db column datatype and size? Just to make sure its Varchar2.

Comment: I have updated the main question description with the code.

Comment: `3421: Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation` is not an Oracle message. Are you invoking this procedure through some sort of API, which perhaps believes that there's a limit on how long the string can be? Also, the `VAR33` parameter is not used in the procedure, so what's the point of having it there in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE   SP_TESTPROC 
     (VAR33  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
      RC1 IN OUT OMWB_EMULATION.GLOBALPKG.RCT1)
AS

BEGIN
   VAR33 := regexp_replace(VAR33, '[^,0-9]', '');

    OPEN RC1 FOR
      SELECT *
      ..........
      ..........
      ..........
END SP_TESTPROC;
```

the above will remove all unwanted and "hidden" characters from the string.
For example, if you are calling the procedure in this way in your code:

```
proc_name('1234,2345,
           2345,5432,
           4545,7777', ..... )
```

then the string contains a few hidden line feed characters and some spaces, and these characters are obvioulsy 'not number' - but the procedure is trying to convert them into the number using `to_number`.

Take a look at this demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f270bc/1

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  x varchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES(
       '1234,2345,
        2345,5432,
        4545,7777'
);
select x, dump(x)
from t;
```

and you will see that a dump of the output contains some 'hidden' charachers (20-space, 10-line feed):
    Typ=1 Len=47: 49,50,51,52,44,50,51,52,53,44,**10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32**,50,51,52,53,44,

53,52,51,50,44,**10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32**,52,53,52,53,44,55,55,55,55